# Passing object from parent controller to isolated scope child directive

Tags: angularjs

I have an object that I want watched inside a directive.
The directive has isolated scope and the object comes from a parent controller.

**DOM:**
`<div hello-directive obj-to-track="{{myObj}}"></div>`

**Directive JS:**

```
scope:{
   objToTrack:'@'
},
link:function(scope,element,attrs){
   scope.$watch(function(newValue){
      //Inside here, newValue is a JSON string
      //So is scope.objToTrack
   });
}
```

Is there anyway to get an actual object from the parent controller besides `JSON.parse()`
Thanks.

Comment: you seem to be getting confused between object and JSON. JSON is a data delivery string format. Inside your app you are dealing with objects and arrays derived from that data that was delivered

Comment: Not sure why you think I'm confused.

Comment: ok...explain comment `Inside here, newValue is a JSON string`. That doesn't make much sense to read

Comment: It means `newValue` is a valid JSON string, not sure what's unclear, sorry.

Comment: again that makes no sense unless your application is dealing with displaying JSON as code and scope properties contain strings of JSON

Comment: I am asking because this question is in the context of Angular and it's what Angular does when using `@` with objects, it passes them to the directive scope as JSON strings. It's not what I want, it's what happens.

Comment: no...`@` passes the literal value of the attribute. I see your issue now...if you want object refernce you use `=` in directive scope. Looking at comment below...you can always watch the object, and make a copy if it changes....and use copy in markup....`angular.copy()`

Comment: `@` converts the Object to JSON string. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the `"="` binding:

```
scope:{
    objToTrack: "="
}
```

Watch it as usual:

```
scope.$watch("objToTrack", function(newval, oldval) {
    ...
});
```

Use it as:

```
<div hello-directive obj-to-track="myObj"></div>
```

Comment: I know, but that enables two-way binding. It's not a *huge* issue, but I'd rather not let the directive be able to write to it if possible. If it's not possible, then it will have to do.

Comment: You cannot disallow writting - unless `myObj` is a "primitive" value. I mean even if you pass a copy of the reference to `myObj`, the directive still has access to the actual members of `myObj`. It could be done if you `angular.copy()`-ied the object before passing it to the directive, possibly in combination with the `"&"` binding, but this is probably more cumbersome.

Comment: I was having the same requirement and bumped into this question. I could'nt understand what @NikosParaskevopoulos says, then found this great explanation which answered the question, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482